# How do you change the trailing character in a URI from # to / in <rdf:RDF xmlns=""> - owl api

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I am using OWL API 4.0.1 and whenever I export OWL I end up with a hash at the end of a URI in the rdf:RDF xmlns section, example below.

```xml
 <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.example.com/example/Example#">
```

However I don't want the hash, I want to use the 303 URI separator of '/' from [*Cool URIs for the Semantic Web*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cooluris/) and look like:

```xml
 <rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.example.com/example/Example/">
```

What would I need to do to change the trailing character from # to / in the rdf:RDF xmlns="" section?

Comment: What the default namespace is in the RDF/XML serialization doesn't matter as much as what's getting concatenated with it.  E.g., do your elements look like `<Person><hasName>John</hasName></Person>`.  If they do, it means you're using the URIs `...#Person`.  The prefixes/namespaces in the serialization aren't as important as the the URIs that you use in your code.  Be sure that you're using the `/` versions when you're *constructing* the data.

Comment: Morning, The Uri I am using is example.com/example/Example and I don't have a single # anywhere in my code but it still prints out example.com/example/Example#, this is causing me a bit of confusion. I output my file in rdfs/xml and the namespace I am sending over is http://www.example.com/example/. I will have to look at the code some more then and see if I have a hash somewhere in there  that I don't see.

Comment: My point though, is that the empty prefix defined by  xmlns="..." doesn't matter if nothing's getting resolved against it. is anything?

Answer (score 0):

The RDF/XML namespaces are used as prefixes in URIs in that particular serialization.  Even if the empty namespace defined with `xmlns="...#"` happens to end with a `#`, it doesn't matter unless there's something in the document that actually *uses* the empty namespace.  E.g., the following RDF/XML document has a namespace like the one that you describe:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns="http://example.com/example#"
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:ex="http://example.com/example/">
  <ex:Thing rdf:about="http://example.com/example/Example"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

That said, the document only has one triple, and neither of the "example" URIs have a `#` in them:

```
<http://example.com/example/Example> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/example/Thing> .
```

I'd suggest that you try writing out your model using the N-Triples serialization so that all the URIs are written out in full.  Then you can do a plain text search for the problematic URI, `...#`, and see whether it's actually occurring somewhere in the model or not.  Just because it's defined as a prefix in the RDF/XML serialization doesn't mean that there's actually a URI *starting* with that prefix in the model.